# how to expand the dimensions of a tensor in pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch, pytorch-dataloader

i'm a newcomer for pytorch. if i have a tensor like that:

> **A = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [ 4, 5, 6]])**,

but my question is how to get a 2 dimensions tensor like:

```
B =  Tensor([[[1, 2, 3],
                           [4, 5, 6]], 

                          [[1, 2, 3], 
                           [4, 5, 6]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate ...

```
A
tensor([[[1., 2., 3.],
         [4., 5., 6.]]])
B = torch.cat((a, a))

B
tensor([[[1., 2., 3.],
         [4., 5., 6.]],

        [[1., 2., 3.],
         [4., 5., 6.]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [repeat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.repeat.html) function like this

```py
B = A.repeat(2, 1, 1)
```